# Angle between two straight lines (tangent formula)

Tags: geometry

Given the points $A(4,4)$ and $B(7,0)$ which are vertices of the triangle $OAB$, where $O$ I assume is the origin, I have to find an equation of the line that bisects the angle $OBA$. There is a neat formula: $$\tan \alpha =\left|\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1 m_2}\right|$$

Above is for acute angle between two straight lines. Where $\alpha$ is the angle between two straight lines and $m_1$ and $m_2$ are the slopes of those lines.

Since we have a point $B$, we only need a slope to form an equation of the line that bisects the angle. Now the slope can be written in two ways, thus forming an equation that is possible to be solved.

First equation: $$\left| \frac{0-m_2}{1}\right| = m_2$$
Second equation: $$\left| \frac{m_2+\frac{4}{3}}{1-\frac{4m_2}{3}}\right|$$

And then the slope should be found by equating the above two... But the answer is meaningless.. it is $i$.. And I have to keep it real.. Clearly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $m_2$ is **negative**, you have to have
$$\left|\frac{0-m_2}{1}\right|=\color{red}{-}m_2.$$

So, you'll have
$$-m_2=\left|\frac{m_2+\frac 43}{1-\frac{4m_2}{3}}\right|$$
which should give $m_2=-\frac 12$.

Comment: But if I leave it negative then I will be looking at obtuse angle, no? And how is the modulus of negative $m_2$ equals $m_2$?

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: For the first, no, $m_2$ is the slope, not $\alpha$, so it can be negative. For the second, we have $|-m_2|=|m_2|$ and $|m_2|=-m_2$ because for $x\lt 0$, $|x|=-x$.

Comment: It does help indeed. But how would I see myself, that the result of the first equation has to be negative. At the time of writing that equation I did not know whether $m_2$ would end up negative. I always have problems with modulus.

Comment: I could have well written the first equation as $\frac{m_2-0}{1}$

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: I drew the triangle, then knew that $m_2$ is negative. So, drawing should help. Also, for modulus, going to back to the definition should help : $|x|=x$ for $x\ge 0$ and $|x|=-x$ for $x\lt 0$. For our example, $|\frac{0-m_2}{1}|=|\frac{m_2-0}{1}|$ is correct, but this is not equal to $\frac{m_2-0}{1}$ : $|\frac{0-m_2}{1}|=|\frac{m_2-0}{1}|=\frac{|m_2-0|}{|1|}=|m_2|=\color{red}{-}m_2$. I hope this helps.

Comment: Now that completely clarified it. That definition was very useful. Thank you!

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: You are welcome!

Comment: one more question. Sorry. What about the second equation. How do I know that I have to write it in that way and not $\left | \frac{-4/3-m_2}{1-(4m_2)/3}\right|$? Thanks

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Setting $m_1=-\frac 43$ in $\left|(m_1-m_2)/(1+m_1m_2)\right|$ gives you $\left|\frac{-4/3-m_2}{1-(4m_2)/3}\right|$. So, you are right. Now note that we can have $|\frac{-4/3-m_2}{1-(4m_2)/3}|=|\frac{m_2+(4/3)}{1-(4m_2)/3}|$ because in general we have $|-A|=|A|$ for every $A\in\mathbb R$, which means that you can multiply the number inside the modulus by $-1$.

Comment: I just realised, in first equation, according to our definition of modulus, the result should be: $\left| -m_2 \right| = -(-m_2) = m_2$, no?

Comment: I suppose your comment immediately above the one above this one, explains why it is actually $-m_2$....

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: Yes, all clear?

Comment: One last question. I wonder whether I keep saying that and not keeping my word haha. So I now understand that I can multiply whatever is inside the modulus by -1. But how do I know that I should drop the modulus for the positive expression in second equation. Because if I drop the modulus for the one multiplied by -1, I once again obtain $i$ as the solution. I.e. It is quite clear that $|m_2|=-m_2$, because we can see that from graph. But since we don't know the magnitude of that "negativeness", how do we verify that second equation is not negative when we drop modulus? Sorry if I'm being slow

Comment: @isquared-KeepitReal: If I'm understand you correctly, I guess that you are talking about how to find $m_2$. Solving $-m_2=\left|\frac{m_2+(4/3)}{1-(4m_2/3)}\right|$ is not so easy. We have $-m_2=\frac{|m_2+(4/3)|}{|1-(4m_2/3)|}$. Here, since we know that $m_2$ is negative, we know that $1-(4m_2/3)$ is positive. Thus, $|1-(4m_2/3)|=1-(4m_2/3)$. So, we have $-m_2(1-\frac{4m_2}{3})=|m_2+\frac 43|$. From here, let us separate it into cases : for $m_2+\frac 43\lt 0$, or for $m_2+\frac 43\ge 0$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for. I see then, so there are indeed cases. And then if the answer to one case does not make sense it simply means it is not a valid solution. Perfect! This was actually just a part of the problem. Next you have to show that if C is the point at which bisector and OA meet, then it divides OA in the ratio OB:BA, which is equivalent to OC:CA. But I have solved that. I keep having issues with modulus, hopefully this has clarified everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternate method that should work:

Draw the line through $(4,4)$ perpendicular to the angle bisector, and let $(x,0)$ be the x-intercept of this line.

By congruent triangles, $\;\;d((x,0), (7,0))=d((4,4),(7,0))=5$, so $x=2$.

Then the midpoint $(3,2)$ of the line segment from $(4,4)$ to $(2,0)$ lies on the angle bisector,

so it has equation $y-0=\frac{2}{-4}(x-7)$ or $y=-\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{7}{2}$.

Comment: +1 for using geometric skill to solve an analytic-geometric problem.